# MPMoviePlayerController does not remove view when clicking done

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am creating a MPMoviePlayerController object and streaming a video in full screen mode.

I am using a UIViewController to display the movie view.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ebeQaznNcmE
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url]; 
    mPlayer.view.frame = gMainView.frame;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                            object:mPlayer];
    mPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    mPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [gMainView addSubview:mPlayer.view];
    [mPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [mPlayer play];
}


- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    int reason = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        //movie finished playing
    }
    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        //user hit the done button
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                      object:moviePlayer];

        if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
            [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [moviePlayer release];
    }
    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
        //error
    }
}
```

When clicking done, the video visual is removed from the screen, but the controls are not removed from the screen and the view is not removed from the screen.

The control does come to "//user hit the done button". It does execute the code to remove the view from superview, I checked by adding logs, **but the controls are not removed from the screen and the view is not removed from the screen**.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I use MPMoviePlayerViewController then it doesn't even wait for me to press Done. Once the video is complete it automatically removes the view. But I don' want that.

**EDIT:**

If I remove "[mPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]" then when clicking on Done, the view is removed completely. But the video is not displayed in full screen and the status bar goes gray which is again what I don't want.

Comment: You take many steps to describe what you do not want but, at least to me, this does still not really state what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: The controls are not removed from the screen and the player view is not removed from the screen.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142571/mpmovieplayer-done-button-issue/6142685#6142685

Comment: @Anand i ma getting same problem with MPmoviePlayerController .hav you got any answer .if please let me know...thanks

Answer (score 10):

The below code worked for me, Hope it helps you too.

```
-(IBAction)playVedio:(id)sender{
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

}

-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification  {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [mp.moviePlayer stop];
    mp = nil;
    [mp release];
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];  
}
```

Comment: Please Sirji also add something more with the code that other can easily understand your answer that what have you done and what was the problem with the code in Question what have you done to overcome it, anyways thanks for the solution :)

Comment: vl take care abt that next time..!!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;

    if (window && [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"]) {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    } else {

        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))

        {

        }

        else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))

        {


        }

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

        CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
        CGSize size = frame.size;
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rotation: %s [w=%f, h=%f]",
                      UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation) ? "Portrait" : "Landscape",
                      size.width, size.height]);
    }
}
```