# MPMoviePlayerViewController still working after close - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I click on "Done" button to close MPMoviePlayerViewController BEFORE complete connection to url (BEFORE display video), it will still working at backend. Video's Sound will be heard after a while (when connection be completed).

What is the problem ?

My code:

```
- (void) showVideo:(NSString *)vurl
{
    NSDictionary *videos;
    videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vurl]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:mp];

   [mp.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [_window.rootViewController.view addSubview:mp.view];
    [mp release];
}
```

The notification code:

```
- moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:(NSNotification *)theNotification {
ImageTargetsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ImageTargetsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [theNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player.moviePlayer stop];
    [player release];
}
```

The problem is the same if I work on MPMoviePlayerController too. I'm working on iOS 7.1.

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayerController does not remove view when clicking done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564419/mpmovieplayercontroller-does-not-remove-view-when-clicking-done)

Comment: I saw this question, but my problem is different, video view is removed correctly, but after a while you can hear the sound of video beginning to play.