# Displaying and hiding an MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie, objective-c-2.0

I'm using [the code in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142571/mpmovieplayer-done-button-issue) to hide a full screen `MPMoviePlayerController` after the user taps "done". Unfortunately,when he does so, the movie disappears, it also stops, but the screen remains black. Why?

---

Strange thing happened : I changed the style of the `MPMoviePlayerController` to `MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly` and the movie controller does not display volume but does display full screen, fast forward, play, ... buttons. When tapping done or quitting full screen, everything works as desired. The `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification` is never called.

Is this a bug, maybe in the simulator???

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: The view underneath it. For example, I got a button in a view that says "play", when you tap it, it plays the movie. When the movie is finished or the user presses done, the screen remains black.

Comment: In that case I can assure you that you did not 100% follow the instructions from the given thread - there must be something different in your implementation. In case you do not see any difference, go ahead and post your sources in a version that does show the described issue but is reduced as much as possible.

Comment: My class does get notified, the movie does stop and disappear, but my view underneath doesn't "re-appear". I'll mess around a bit, it might be an underlying issue.

Comment: You are assigning an incompatible type to the style property - check the references. Additionally the controlMode is entirely deprecated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see a warning so I thought it'd be okay. Weird that XCode didn't tell me about it.