# MPMoviePlayerController Wont Disappear

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.5

I have been trying all day but for some reason on IOS6 im having so many issues with MPMoviePlayerController, it seemed people have had issues but not similar enough to mine:

The movie loads up and plays fine, when it completes the movie. I can loop the movie. The issue arises when I try to close and remove the movie like so:

If I add the controls to the Movie itself and hit the "Done" button, the movie sort of just pauses &  never closes!

Any tips/ideas?

```
_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:_moviePlayerController];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackLoaded:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification  
                                           object:_moviePlayerController];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                             name:kMovieOverlayViewTapped
                                           object:nil];


[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];  
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
```

-

Now on Playback loaded:

```
- (void)moviePlaybackLoaded:(NSNotification *)notification  
{   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification  
                                                  object:_moviePlayerController]; 

_moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[_moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 100, 250, 163)];
[_moviePlayerController play];
```

}

now to remove the video:

```
 - (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                      object:_moviePlayerController];  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification  
                                                  object:_moviePlayerController]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:kMovieOverlayViewTapped
                                                  object:nil]; 

[_moviePlayerController stop];
[_moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];       
    _moviePlayerController = nil;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayer done button issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142571/mpmovieplayer-done-button-issue)

Comment: Like I said, I have tried that. DONE works fine but I want the same behaviour if I close the movie myself.

Comment: I gave solved it, I wasnt unsubscribing from the playbackLoaded message, so it was being fired multiple times.