# Large size video not playing in fullscreen mode using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
     self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height>480)
        [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, _viewVideoArea.frame.size.width, _viewVideoArea.frame.size.height)];
    else
        [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, _viewVideoArea.frame.size.width, 383)];

    [self.viewVideoArea addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    [self.videoController prepareToPlay];
    [self.videoController play];
```

Above code is my initialisation of my player. Large size video playing when the player not in full screen mode but not playing in fullscreen mode. Then also any button in fullscreen mode not respond(Including Done button).

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142571/mpmovieplayer-done-button-issue) Also try this for respond done button but not working.. Dont know what is the issue going on.

Can any one pls help me to solve my prob

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
self.videoController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i ll try and let you know